# Vue - when and why using $el

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog

I've found this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50431015/11735826
and i wonder why .$el was used here, and also why does it not work without the el element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you use `ref` attribute on the html tag, the DOM-element is returned by `this.$refs.modal`.

when you use `ref` attribute on the template tag, the component instance is returned, so `this.$refs.modal.$el` returns directly the DOM element. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el

Answer (score 2):

`$el` returns the HTML element to which a given Vue instance (be it a main instance or a component) is bound. By using `this.$refs.modal.$el` the answer gets the underlying HTML element for the `this.$refs.modal`, and then encapsulates it in a jQuery object to call the modal method.